# Issue Installing "RGtk2" Package for R Data Miner

Tags: r

After running rattle(), the following pops up:

```
Error in rattle() : 
The RGtk2 package is not available but is required. 
Please install the package using, for example: 

  install.packages("RGtk2")
```

After running the above install command, the following pops up:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RGtk2’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Then

```
install_github("cran/RGtk2")
```

Output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In missing_devel_warning(pkgdir) :
  Package RGtk2 has compiled code, but no suitable compiler(s) were found. Installation will likely fail.
  Install Rtools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).Then use the pkgbuild package, or make sure that Rtools in the PATH.
2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/SAAD/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpgv8fo6/file2344490d6025/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The "RGtk2" package isn't available in the CRAN repository.
I am currently using R 4.2.1 version. Newer version of RGtk2 package isn't available in the archive, only older versions are available, which I believe aren't compatible with the current version. How to install it?

I have tried all the methods and wasted a lot of time to install the RGtk2 package in order to use the R data mining tool, ranging from penetrating several websites for resolution, downloading various versions of package archive files and trying to install the package, etc., but all efforts in vain.
Therefore, currently seeking authentic solution from experienced folks. Is there any other way to use the R data mining tool? There isn't any straightforward and quick method to install archived packages; as R gets updated, so all the packages should.

Comment: You can try installing Rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ as the error message suggested if you want to try to build the package from source for your R version. But note that since the package is no longer supposed, there's no guarantee that it will ever work with newer versions of R. If you absolutely need to use that pacakge, you're probably better off using an older version of R as well -- what ever was available at the time the package was last available.

Comment: @MrFlick None of the methods worked. It is too annoying; there isn't any solution to it. Why can't the question be posted to the community?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation at https://rattle.togaware.com/. There are installation instructions there for RGtk2

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, long back. It didn't work. Now I tried again, still no use. If any other working alternative, kindly provide. How come such expert R package developers aren't worried about the same? R is such an amazing language/tool, but they don't pay any heed to upgrading the very useful, earlier packages. There isn't any straightforward and quick method to install archived packages; as R gets updated, so all the packages should.